# Long file paths using Git via TeamCity

Tags: git, teamcity

I am using TeamCity with Git and attempting to do a git checkout on the individual agent (This is part of a CI pipeline that will have to switch branches at some point, so I need the correct Git files in the working folder).

Within our repository, we have long file names that are usually too long for Git to handle. These are NPM modules and cannot be removed from source control at this point in time. If you checkout the repository on a clean machine, you will get an error similar to the following.

> cannot create directory at '****/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/fs-extra/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/balanced-match/test': Filename too long

When cloning the repo locally on a developers machine, you have to call

> git config --system core.longpaths true

And then everything is rosy.

On a TeamCity build agent, I have done the same. When I call

> git config --list

I can see that longpaths are enabled. When I do a checkout using git on that machine, I can also download the repository fine.

However when I kick off a build from TeamCity, I get the same Filename too long error. I've restarted the machine (Turn it off and on again), and still no dice.

Comment: Please ensure that you enabled long paths under the user who runs TeamCity agent. Also i'd check if there are serveral git versions on the agent: if TeamCity uses some old version then longpaths might not work. If it doesn't help please check if the error is a result of a git command or thrown by TeamCity, if latter is the case provide full error with stacktrace if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

In general, running `git config --system core.longpaths true` on Agent machine should be enough - it sets the config system-wide (not per-user).

One of the reasons why this may not work is that your Teamcity Agent uses different git instance (git.exe from different path) than your commandline. You can force Teamcity to use the same instance:

1. Check git.exe location from commandline: run `which git`. Alternatively, run `git config --system --edit` and check the location of edited config file.
2. configure TeamCity to use git from that path: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Git#Git-Gitexecutableontheagent

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user for the TeamCity service and agent, then change both service to run under that user. Next login to Windows with that user, and run the git config command. Or figure out how to set the global option for "core.longpaths"